# Convert multiple .jpg files to .bmp files

Tags: jpeg, file-conversion, bmp

I am currently making a game with iGraphics, and for that I have to use images only in .bmp format. I have multiple .jpg images, and I want to convert all of them to .bmp format. Just changing the extension didn't work for me, I have to open each image in MS paint and then save that image as .bmp format. I have to do this for all the images one by one. Is there any way to convert all of them at once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/269219/how-can-i-batch-convert-multiple-folders-of-images-to-png8 - at least this should give you an idea of what to search for, and hopefully how to ask a well-defined question if you still can't find a suitable tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I batch convert multiple folders of images to PNG8?](https://superuser.com/questions/269219/how-can-i-batch-convert-multiple-folders-of-images-to-png8)

Comment: there are so many duplicates: [Batch conversion for images from command line on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/643043/241386), [How to convert multiple images at once from JPEG to PNG?](https://superuser.com/q/1445955/241386), [Command line tool for image conversion](https://superuser.com/q/488087/241386), [Using Gimp to batch convert images to another format in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/77429/241386), [best freeware for doing batch conversion of jpg to png](https://superuser.com/q/162060/241386)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line tool for image conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/488087/command-line-tool-for-image-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

> I have multiple `.jpg` images and I want to convert all of them to `.bmp` format.

One possible solution is to use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). ImageMagick is a free, open-source cross-platform command line tool for image manipulation. You can download a copy [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

After installing ImageMagick, you can add `magick.exe` to your Windows path and use the following in a command window (wherever your images are stored):

```
magick mogrify -format bmp *.jpg
```

If you don't wish to add `magick.exe` to your path, you can always specify its full path instead.

Answer (score 0):

While i prefer using magick (like the other poster), before i started using commandline tools i used irfanview for the same thing.

I think it uses magick in background, but gives a nice gui.

Copied from [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/50519/simple-batch-conversion-using-irfanview).

It's not my own solution, but its copied from my bookmarks, from what i used for the same/similar things.

> written by tg1911
>
> Instructions
>
> Open Irfanview, and click on File, in the Toolbar, and select Batch
>   Conversion/Rename.... This will open the Batch conversion dialog box.
>
> In the Look in: box, navigate to the images you want to convert.
>
> Select (single Left click) the images to be converted, then click the
>   Add button. This will add the selected file to the Input files: box,
>   to the left of the Add button.
>
> Next, you need to decide where you want the files to be placed, after
>   converting. If you want the images to be placed in the same folder you
>   loaded them from, click the Use this directory as output button.
>
> If you want to put them in a different folder, under Output
>   directory:, click the Browse button, and navigate to where you want
>   them placed. Under Work as:, select Batch conversion.
>
> Under Batch conversion settings, use the drop down arrow to select the
>   Output format. If you don't want to change the file format (jpeg, gif,
>   bmp, etc.), just select the format the images are already in.
>
> Use the Options button to change the image quality. The format you
>   use, will determine if the Options button is active, or not.
>
> More on setting image quality, can be found in this tutorial: Reducing
>   An Image's File Size By Reducing It's Image Quality Using Irfanview If
>   you want to use advanced options, put a check in the box next to Use
>   advanced options. This will activate the Set advanced options button.
>
> Clicking the Set advanced options button, will open the Settings for
>   all images: dialog box.
>
> This is where you set the changes, you want to make to the images.
>
> Putting a check in the box, next to the operation you want to perform,
>   will activate the settings.
>
> When you have it set the way you want it, click the OK button.
>
> This will bring you back to the Batch conversion dialog box.
>
> If everything is set the way you want it, click the Start button.
>
> A dialog box will open, showing the files being processed.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: Changed. Sorry about not doing it properly the first time :)